# Как сделать чтобы при смещении на следующую строку через флекс марджин убирался и блок смещался вправо?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть `innerBlock2`, в нём текст. Когда он смещается на следующую строку, нужно чтобы он ставился в правую часть и убирался `margin`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

#innerBlock2 {
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

#innerBlock {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div id="innerBlock"></div>
  <div id="innerBlock2">
    <h4>lorem</h4>
    <h4>lorem</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В CSS для блока `#innerBlock2` добавляем новое правило: `flex-grow: 1;`

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var mainBlock = document.getElementById('block'),
      innerBlock2 = document.getElementById('innerBlock2');

  if (mainBlock.clientWidth === innerBlock2.clientWidth) {
    mainBlock.style.justifyContent = 'flex-end';
    innerBlock2.style.marginTop = 0;
    innerBlock2.style.maxWidth = '200px';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

#innerBlock2 {
  margin-top: 20vh;
  display: flex;
}

#innerBlock {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}

#innerBlock2 h4:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div id="innerBlock"></div>
  <div id="innerBlock2">
    <h4>lorem</h4>
    <h4>lorem</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```